# Two classes which have instances of each other ,give a stack over flow error

Tags: java

There are two classes : Calculator  and MenubarListener .
The Calculator class has an instance of MenubarListener , and now in MenubarListener class I need to access two methods of the Calculator class and invoke them .but when I make an instance of Calculator inside MenubarListener the compiler shows stack over flow error. obviously  it falls in a loop I know why it happens but I can't find a proper solution .on the other hand  I don't want to make these methods static,otherwise that will create other problems.
How  can I access these two methods through the second class ?

Calculator class:

```
public class Calculator{

    MenuBarListener menubarListener = new menubarListener(a,b,c);
            .
            .
            .
    public void method1{
     //do something     
    }
    public void method2{
     //do something 
    }
 }
```

MenubarListener class :

```
public class MenubarListener {

//when I make an instance of calculator class compiler shows stackoverflow error.
Calculator calculator = new Calculator;

int a, b,c;
MenubarListener (int a ,int b,int c ){
this.a = a ;
...   }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == helpItem) {
    //I want to access these methods from Calculator class but it generates
       calculator.method1();
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Take a step back.  Clearly each class shouldn't *create* an instance of the other class, as that is an endless cycle.  Instead, which class should *require* that an instance of the other class be *provided* to it?  For example, suppose you have a `Window` object and a `Menu` object which goes in the Window.  The Window object would *create* (and effectively own) an instance of the Menu.  If the Menu needs to interact with its "parent" Window then it would require a Window reference in its constructor, which the Window object would provide when creating the Menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT be creating a new instance of `Calculator` inside `MenubarListener`, just pass the reference to the `Calculator` via constructor/setter:

```java
public class Calculator{

    MenuBarListener menubarListener = new MenuBarListener(this, 10, 20, 30);
//...
}
```

```java
public class MenuBarListener {

    final Calculator calculator;

    int a, b, c;

    MenuBarListener (Calculator calc, int a, int b, int c) {
        this.calculator = calc;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
// ...
}
```

Comment: thank you bro . it works . but I didn't get the concept of your solution . could you give more information why we do this .? best regards

Comment: It is explained in David's comment below the question: there's a cycle: create Calculator -> create MenuBarListener (MBL) -> create Calc -> create MBL ... without end.  The other solution might be to follow the usual pattern of implementing the listener class as _inner_ class of `Calculator` or another UI `Window` and as such it has access to the fields / methods of the outer class.